# How to set login page as default landing page in ASP.NET Razor Pages?

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages, asp.net-core-identity, asp.net-core-5.0, c#-10.0

I am new to Razor Pages and creating a small web app in ASP.NET Core 5 with Individual Authentication. I want that whenever my application is loaded, login page should open as a landing page and then after logged in it should redirect to home page.

Here is the code I added in my Startup.cs file

```
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddInfrastructure(Configuration);
            services.AddMvc().AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
            {
                options.Conventions.AddAreaPageRoute("Identity", "/Account/Login", "");
            });
            services.AddRazorPages();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            }

            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {                   
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            });
        }
    }
```

The problem is after successful login and register, the application is not redirecting to home page. It stays on Login Page.

[image: Project Snapshot]

Can anybody guide me where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Add on Razor page

```
@page "/Login"

 [AllowAnonymous]
 public class IndexModel : PageModel
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).